# in javascript creating object and manipulating properties

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, object-construction

I create objects by two different ways and try to reach them and manipulate them. The object that I create by object constructor it work but same thing I try to do by literal notation doesn't work. I don't understand.

here is code it will explain itself better than me:

```
var numberOne = new Object();
rand = Math.random();
numberOne[rand] = "random number";
console.log(numberOne); //return 0.6761925128922479: "random number"



var numberTwo = {}; //code doesnt work.
numberTwo.rando = Math.random();
numberTwo[rando] = "another random number";

console.log(numberTwo); //error
```

Comment: You may use numberTwo["rando"] for accessing rando field in numberTwo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't work because your index random is saved into numberTwo object and not in rando variable. You need to refer to index saved into numberTwo object, like this:

```
 numberTwo[numberTwo.rando];
```

so, your code must be like this:

```
var numberTwo = {}; 
numberTwo.rando = Math.random(); // numberTwo.rando contains some random number
numberTwo[numberTwo.rando] = "another random number"; //now it is correct
```

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
var numberTwo = {};
rand = Math.random();
numberTwo[rand] = "another random number";
console.log(numberTwo);
```

In your solution `numberTwo` didn't initialize `rand` property

Comment: I wanna get something like: 0.6761925128922479: "another random number". Yours is different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
var numberOne = new Object();
var rand = Math.random();
numberOne[rand] = "random number";
console.log(numberOne);

var numberTwo = {};
rand = Math.random();
numberTwo[rand] = "another random number";

console.log(numberTwo);
```

Your code breaks at `numberTwo[rando] = "another random number";` because `rando` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Those two are not equivalent.

In the first one, you create a property whose name is a random number and assign that property a string as a value:

```
rand = Math.random();
numberOne[rand] = "random number";
```

Your testing shows this: `//return 0.6761925128922479: "random number"`

In the second one, you create a property called "rando" and assign it a value that is a random number. Then you try to assign a string value to a non-existant property, because you are using `rando` (a non-existant variable) instead of `"rando"` (a string) to try to access the property that you created earlier.

```
numberTwo.rando = Math.random();
numberTwo[rando] = "another random number";
```

If you used the same approach for both, they would both work.  Like this:

```
var numberOne = new Object();
rand = Math.random();
numberOne[rand] = "random number";
console.log(numberOne);

var numberTwo = {};
rando = Math.random(); // <---- The different line
numberTwo[rando] = "another random number";
console.log(numberTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are not the same things.

In the first case you assign a string to a randomly generated key.

```
var numberOne = new Object();  // create an object
rand = Math.random();  // make a random number
numberOne[rand] = "random number";  // use the random number as a key name and assign the string as its value
```

In the second you assign a random number to a key named `rando`, then try to assign a string to a key that is named as whatever the `rando` variable is (which is undefined).

```
var numberTwo = {}; // create an object.
numberTwo.rando = Math.random();  // assign a random number to key named rando
numberTwo[rando] = "another random number";  // here, rando is undefined variable and causes an error.
```

To make the second example work just do wkat you did in the first one, just change the new Object constructor to an object literal, or:

```
var numberTwo = {}; // create an object.
numberTwo.rando = Math.random();  // assign a random number to key named rando
numberTwo[numberTwo.rando] = "another random number";   // use the value of numberTwo.rando as a key name
```

Now `numberTwo` looks like this:

`Object {rando: 0.7977171319071203, 0.7977171319071203: "another random number"}`

The key difference here is that `object.keyname = x` assigns a value to a key named `keyname`, while `object[keyname] = x` resolves the value of a variable named `keyname` and assigns the value to a key named with the value. (for example `var keyname = "xy"; object[keyname] = 'x';` will result in an object `{ xy: 'x' }`.